# Xcode how to change default code generation when binding IBOutlets from storyboard to code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When dragging an outlet from storyboard to a UIViewController using Xcode split view, it generates the corresponding outlet in code :

[image: Outlet binding]

When generating the outlet code it will always be referenced as `weak var ...` like so :

```
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
```

However in my project the policy is to set them `private` and `strong` like so:

```
@IBOutlet private var titleLabel: UILabel!
```

Is there a way to change the **default code generation** within Xcode to set your own rules when binding outlets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think can't change default code generation. Maybe It is hardfix by algorithm in function `-[IBSwiftOutletSourceCodeConnectionContext prepareToInsertSourceCode:]` in `IDEInterfaceBuilderKit` framework.

Comment: by curiosity, how did you access these functions? in XCode source code?

Comment: @Olympiloutre I use spindump

Comment: not familiar with spindump but you actually saw this method being called but not the actual source code behind, isnt it?

Comment: Yep, I found `-[IDESourceCodeGenerator prepareToAddSourceCodeForCounterparts:documentLocationForCounterpartBlock:addSourceCodeForCounterpartBlock:options:error:]` in `IDEKit` method generate code when insert source code outlet.

Comment: Is it possible that this method load a template file within `XCode.app` bundle?

Comment: @Olympiloutre I don't know.

Comment: @Olympiloutre assembly very complex, I can't read to find answer how to change.